# installing nodejs in dockerfile issue

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to install nodejs in dockerfile with pyenv but I keep getting this error when I run it through my gitlab runner. I am trying to install version 16.12.0. Is there a better solution to this issue?

Dockerfile

```
#install npm
ENV NODE_VERSION=16.12.0
RUN apt install -y curl
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version
```

output

```
Step 15/25 : ENV NODE_VERSION=16.12.0
 ---> Running in 7623dfe4669c
Removing intermediate container 7623dfe4669c
 ---> c1486340596a
Step 16/25 : RUN apt install -y curl
 ---> Running in a4661b68566b
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
curl is already the newest version (7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Removing intermediate container a4661b68566b
 ---> d727779ba39b
Step 17/25 : RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
 ---> Running in c3661e8eead3
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
Removing intermediate container c3661e8eead3
 ---> beffd784c86b
Step 18/25 : ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
 ---> Running in 22b69a1563b2
Removing intermediate container 22b69a1563b2
 ---> 821b73dfd5fa
Step 19/25 : RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
 ---> Running in 54c168c88ec7
/bin/sh: 1: .: Can't open /root/.nvm/nvm.sh
The command '/bin/sh -c . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}' returned a non-zero code: 127
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

Comment: Do you know if `/root/.nvm` exists and you have permission to write to it?

Comment: What base image are you creating your container from? Have you tried any of the official containers like `node:lts` or `node:lts-alpine`?

Comment: base image is ubunut 20.04

Answer (score 2):

In general you should avoid using version managers like `nvm` in Docker.  You shouldn't need more than one version of a language interpreter at a time, and the version managers often require shell dotfile setup that's complicated to configure in Docker.

You don't say why you need Node.  The easiest thing to do is to use the [Docker Hub `node` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node)

```sh
FROM node:lts
# and none of what you show in the question
```

If you're using this to build the front end of your otherwise Python application, you can use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) for this

```sh
FROM node:lts AS frontend
WORKDIR /frontend
COPY frontend/package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY frontend/ ./
RUN npm build

FROM python:3.10
...
COPY --from=frontend /frontend/dist ./static/
```

If you really need Node in your otherwise Ubuntu-based image, the next easiest thing to do is just install it.  The [default Ubuntu `nodejs` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nodejs) should work fine for most practical uses.

```sh
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get --no-install-recomends --assume-yes \
      nodejs
```

If you really need it in a custom image, and it really needs to be a super specific version of Node, you should be able to just [download Node](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and [install it](https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation).

```sh
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get --no-install-recomends --assume-yes \
      curl \
      xz-utils
ARG node_version=v16.14.2
RUN cd /opt \
 && curl -LO https://nodejs.org/dist/${node_version}/node-${node_version}-linux-x64.tar.xz \
 && tar xJf node-${node_version}-linux-x64.tar.xz \
 && rm node-${node_version}-linux-x64.tar.xz
ENV PATH=/opt/node-${node_version}-linux-x64/bin:${PATH}
```